# SQL: How to set job to get executed annually

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a job in sql.
My requirement is that the job should get executed annually in 31st of march. While creating the steps, i was not able to find Yearly frequency occurance.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366342.aspx) - you'll have to schedule it to run on the 31st of every month. Then, as the first step, detect if its not the 31st of march and cause the job to complete early.

I normally write such steps as an obvious error, and use that to control the flow of the job - something like:

```
IF DATEPART(month,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) != 3
BEGIN
    EXEC('select * from nonexistenttable')
END
```

Comment: Hi. what is the `3` in the `!=3`?

Comment: @WTFZane - the OP wants the job to run once per year, in March. That's not an option, so I've told them to run the job once a month. We then extract the current month and compare it with 3 and force the job to exit if the comparison fails. So, the 3 is "March".

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling across this you can set up a job that runs on a specific day on a rolling basis, in this case every 12 months on March 31st.

Under Frequency - set the day to the 31st of every 12 month(s).
Under Duration - set the start date to March 31st with no end date.

```
sp_add_jobschedule [ @job_id = ] job_id, | [ @job_name = ] 'job_name'
 , @freq_type = 16  
 , @freq_interval = 1  
 , @freq_recurrence_factor = 12
 , @active_start_date = 20180331
```

or

[Job Schedule Setup to run annually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwaEv.jpg)